# Are command tips in Texstudio editable

Tags: texstudio

Texstudio has the nice feature that when I hover the cursor over a command the correct syntax of the command and some helpful hints are shown in a window. I was wondering if the content of these windows is editable and if so where this contents reside and how I can add content for my own commands.

Answer (score 2):

In principle yes. It is extracted from `latexhelp.html`. However, adding content may be a bit cumbersome. Afaik, you have to list the command in the alphabetical index and create a block below. Try copying the structure of an existing command.